# Advanced Google Closure Compiler Optimisation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I've tried to compile my JS+jQuery script with **Google Closure Compiler**. It works alright with the simple optimization option. However, when I switch to advanced optimization some errors occur.

For instance, it changes jQuery **$.ajax()** method to **$.i()**. That simply makes the browser go crazy.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Comment: What do you mean by 'makes the browser go crazy'? What do you observe?

Comment: Why is this tagged with uglifyjs when its about the closure compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advanced optimization will mangle names, including property accesses. In order to use the advanced optimizations, you have to write code specifically *for* that purpose. At the end of a lot of [library code](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer) written for the closure compiler you'll see stuff that looks like this:

```
window['MarkerClusterer'] = MarkerClusterer;
MarkerClusterer.prototype['addMarker'] = MarkerClusterer.prototype.addMarker;
MarkerClusterer.prototype['addMarkers'] = MarkerClusterer.prototype.addMarkers;
MarkerClusterer.prototype['clearMarkers'] = MarkerClusterer.prototype.clearMarkers;
```

or for a simplified example

```
window['myLibraryName'] = myLibrary;
myLibrary['someMethod'] = myLibrary.someMethod;
```

Reason being that the compiler will obviously not mangle string literals and now those names can be properly exported via the `myLibrary` object.

So unless jQuery (or any other library) is specifically written to play nice with the feature, you can't use advanced optimizations. Which is a criticism frequently leveled at the closure compiler. OTOH, this is something that google wrote for themselves, for their own codebase, and were nice enough to give us for free, so...